# data sended to a server is undefined on res.send() method

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension with a log-in, so I'm trying to send data from the popup to a database. I'm currently just sending it to a server and printing in the console the values I get, but the values don't arrive or stay undefined. I'm new to node and servers so I'm probably just having a dummy error. These are the files where I think the problem is:

The popup.html: It has 2 inputboxes and a send button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/toggle_bar.css"-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"/>
        <!--script src="message.js"></script-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2 align="center">
            CTRL
        </h2>

        User: <input type="text" id="User" placeholder="User"><br>
        Password: <input type="text"  placeholder="Password" id="Password" ><br>
        <button type="submit"  id='boton'>ENVIAR</button>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <!--script src="background.js"></script-->
    </body>
</html>
```

the server.js:

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require("path");

let app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

app.post('/CTRL', function(req, res) {
    let usuario = req.body;
    console.log('Nombre: ' + usuario.name + ' password: ' + usuario.passw);
    res.send('Nombre: ' + usuario.name + ' password: ' + usuario.passw);
});

app.listen('8000', function() {
    console.log('server corriendo puerto 8000');
  })
```

and the popup.js:

```
let nombre = document.getElementById('User');
let contrasena = document.getElementById('Password');
let boton = document.getElementById('boton');

boton.addEventListener('click', sendData);

function sendData(){

    let nombreSTR = nombre.value
    let contrasenaSTR = contrasena.value

    let usuario = {
        name: nombreSTR,
        passw: contrasenaSTR
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/CTRL', {
      mode:'no-cors',
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(usuario),
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  }
```

this is what I get in console:

> server corriendo puerto 8000
>
> Nombre: undefined password: undefined

Comment: Isn't `req.body` going to be JSON, so it's just a string? Have you tried logging `usuario` and `typeof usuario`?

Comment: @VLAZ sorry, I dont know where the console for a popup is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In popup.js, the Content-Type is not working because you are using no-cors. Use the following code here -

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/CTRL', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(usuario),
});
```

But then you have to allow CORS in your server.js. Also, you have to use express bodyparser to parse the body properly. Use the following code -

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors');

let app = express();


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.post('/CTRL', function(req, res) {
    let usuario = req.body;
    console.log('Nombre: ' + usuario.name + ' password: ' + usuario.passw);
    res.send('Nombre: ' + usuario.name + ' password: ' + usuario.passw);
});

app.listen('8000', function() {
    console.log('server corriendo puerto 8000');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line of code:

```
let usuario = req.body
```

It has to be :

```
let usuario = req.body.usuario
```

or:

```
let { usuario } = req.body
```